# Odd Bed Error in obfuscated Minecraft build, not present in Development Environment

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So, I have a class I am using to improve the functionality of beds (the player can sleep in them if mobs cannot see them or get to them), and in the development environment, it works perfectly, exactly as expected. When I compile it and drop it into an obfuscated game, however, I run into a significant error. Players get into beds, and then are unable to get back out. I believe it may be due to an error getting fields and methods with Reflection in an obfuscated environment, however I have made functions that should, in theory, deal with that. Any input as to the cause of this bug would be appreciated.

```
package com.reimaginedgaming.blur.jwin.events;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.monster.EntityMob;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.util.AxisAlignedBB;
import net.minecraft.util.ChunkCoordinates;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.player.PlayerSleepInBedEvent;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.asm.transformers.deobf.FMLDeobfuscatingRemapper;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.eventhandler.SubscribeEvent;

public class BedSleepingFix {
private static Field sleeping;
private static Field sleeptimer;
private static Method setsize;
private static Method func_71013_b;
public static void setupFields() {
    Class bed = EntityPlayer.class;
    Class entity = Entity.class;
    try {
        sleeping = getField("sleeping",bed);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ran into error:\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n between lines 34 and 37.");
    }
    try {
        sleeptimer = getField("sleepTimer",bed);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ran into error:\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n between lines 34 and 37.");
    }
    try {
        setsize = getMethod("setSize",entity, float.class, float.class);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ran into error:\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n between lines 34 and 37.");
    }
    try {
        func_71013_b = getMethod("func_71013_b",bed, int.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Ran into error:\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"between lines 23 and 29.");
    }
    try {
    func_71013_b.setAccessible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ran into error:\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n between lines 34 and 37.");
    }
    try {
    setsize.setAccessible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ran into error:\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n between lines 34 and 37.");
    }
    try{
    sleeping.setAccessible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ran into error:\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n between lines 34 and 37.");
    }
    try{
    sleeptimer.setAccessible(true);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Ran into error:\n"+e.getLocalizedMessage()+"\n between lines 34 and 37.");
    }
}
public static Field getField(String methodName, Class classy){
    for(Field i:classy.getDeclaredFields()){
        if(FMLDeobfuscatingRemapper.INSTANCE.isRemappedClass(classy.getName())){
            if(FMLDeobfuscatingRemapper.INSTANCE.unmap(i.getName())==methodName){
                System.out.println("Found Field "+methodName+" as "+i.getName());
                return i;
            }
        } else {
            if(i.getName()==methodName){
                System.out.println("Found Field "+methodName+" as "+methodName);
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public static Method getMethod(String methodName, Class classy, Class... parameters){
    for(Method i:classy.getDeclaredMethods()){
        if(FMLDeobfuscatingRemapper.INSTANCE.isRemappedClass(classy.getName())){
            if(FMLDeobfuscatingRemapper.INSTANCE.unmap(i.getName())==methodName){
                if(arraysAreEqual(i.getParameterTypes(),parameters))
                System.out.println("Found Method "+methodName+" as "+i.getName());
                return i;
            }
        } else {
            if(i.getName()==methodName){
                System.out.println("Found Method "+methodName+" as "+methodName);
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public static boolean arraysAreEqual(Object[] a, Object[] b){
    if(a.length!=b.length)return false;
    int check = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i<=a.length;i++){
        if(a[i]!=b[i]){
            return false;
        }
        check = i;
    }
    if(b[check]!=null)return false;
    return true;
}
@SubscribeEvent
public void sleepfix(PlayerSleepInBedEvent e) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{
    if(e.entity.worldObj.isRemote)return;
    if (!e.entity.worldObj.provider.isSurfaceWorld())return;
    if (e.entity.worldObj.isDaytime())return;
    int d0 = 8;
    int d1 = 8;
    int d2 = 8;
    List list = e.entity.worldObj.getEntitiesWithinAABB(EntityMob.class, AxisAlignedBB.getBoundingBox((double)e.x - d0, (double)e.y - d1, (double)e.z - d0, (double)e.x + d0, (double)e.y + d1, (double)e.z + d0));
    EntityPlayer this1 = e.entityPlayer;
    if (!list.isEmpty())
    {
        boolean lineOfSight = false;
        for(Object i:list){
            EntityMob em = (EntityMob) i;
            if(em.canEntityBeSeen(this1)){
                lineOfSight = true;
                System.out.println("A "+em.getClass().getName()+" can see the player.");
            }
            if(em.getBlockPathWeight((int)this1.posX, (int)this1.posY, (int)this1.posZ)<.2){
                lineOfSight = false;
                System.out.println("A "+em.getClass().getName()+" can reach the player.");
            }
        }
        if(lineOfSight){ 
        System.out.println("Deemed unsafe by JWIN");
        e.result = EntityPlayer.EnumStatus.NOT_SAFE;
        return;
        }

    }
    if (this1.isRiding())
    {
        this1.mountEntity((Entity)null);
    }
    if(setsize!=null)
    setsize.invoke(this1, 0.2F, 0.2F);
    this1.yOffset = 0.2F;
    if(!this1.worldObj.isDaytime()){
    if (this1.worldObj.blockExists(e.x, e.y, e.z))
    {
        int l = this1.worldObj.getBlock(e.x, e.y, e.z).getBedDirection(this1.worldObj, e.x, e.y, e.z);
        float f1 = 0.5F;
        float f = 0.5F;

        switch (l)
        {
            case 0:
                f = 0.9F;
                break;
            case 1:
                f1 = 0.1F;
                break;
            case 2:
                f = 0.1F;
                break;
            case 3:
                f1 = 0.9F;
        }
        if(func_71013_b!=null)
        func_71013_b.invoke(this1, l);
        this1.setPosition((double)((float)e.x + f1), (double)((float)e.y + 0.9375F), (double)((float)e.z + f));
    }
    else
    {
        this1.setPosition((double)((float)e.x + 0.5F), (double)((float)e.y + 0.9375F), (double)((float)e.z + 0.5F));
    }
    System.out.println("Deemed safe by JWIN");
    e.result = EntityPlayer.EnumStatus.OK;
    System.out.println(e.result);
    if(sleeping!=null)
    sleeping.setBoolean(this1,true);
    if(sleeptimer!=null)
    sleeptimer.setInt(this1, 0);
    this1.playerLocation = new ChunkCoordinates(e.x, e.y, e.z);
    this1.motionX = this1.motionZ = this1.motionY = 0.0D;
    if(!this1.worldObj.isRemote)
    this1.worldObj.updateAllPlayersSleepingFlag();
    }
    return;
}
}
```

Again, any help or input at all is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Had to use the obfuscated names located in build\tmp\reobf. Seems to be the only fix that doesn't involve access transformers.